# How to search a name from a list of 10million random names in JAVA?

Tags: java, search

I have an arraylist which can contain 10million random names. What is the most efficient algorithm to search a name and how ?

Comment: Using a database, maybe?

Comment: sort the names so they are not random or use a structure so they are not randomly arranged.  What do you mean by search? Do you have to just check it exists in the list e.g. a `Set` or do you need to look up some associated data e.g. a `Map`

Answer (score 3):

While you have enough memory - sort your list o(n*log(n)) and than use binary search o(ln(n)).

```
List<String> yourNames = ...;
Collections.sort(yourNames);
...

int pos = Collections.binarySearch(yourNames, "tanmoy biswas");
if ( pos < 0 ) { 
  System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

When you will OOM

```
// before sort or do the intern during load of the data
for(int i = 0; i < yourNames.size(); i++) {
    yourNames.set(i, yourNames.get(i).intern());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Searching in an unordered list is not efficient. Here are your options in increasing order of sophistication:

1. The first thing you can do is sort the list. This will let you run binary search across your data. You can find exact matches or prefix matches in O(log(n)) time.
2. One step further: load your data into a `HashSet`. Hash sets are really good at finding exact matches but can do little else.
3. Consider using a database that indexes your data or even Lucene. This is the preferred option as it offers the widest variety of searches.

Comment: HashSet is very memory consuming implementation comparing to plain sorted list, because it contains internally hashmap with references. 10 million values will eat at least 200Mb of extra memory to support the HashSet.

Comment: @ya_pulser Fair point, you don't get something for nothing. Still, if you only want exact matching, but you want it quick, using some sort of hashed set (not necessarily the built-in implementation) is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Without further information I would have to assume you want a Set

```
List<String> list =
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);

// to perform a lookup. This is O(1)
boolean isInArray = set.contains(wordToSearchFor);
```